# Qt ReadyRead and AVR devices

Tags: c++, qt, arduino, serial-port, avr

I have used Qt with an Arduino UNO to build a  data acquisition system.   Now I want to migrate that to Qt with an AVR ATmege32u4 microcontroller.

Please look at the code below.  I am reading incoming serial data with Qt triggered by the ReadyRead signal, then printing those data to the Qt debug window.  This works fine with Qt+UNO, but not Qt+32u4.  I rule out any problems with the 32u4 (e.g. bad chip) because the data are printed fine to the serial port monitor in the Arduino IDE.

My questions are:

(1) why does the program work for one AVR device and not the other?

(2) how can I make the program work for the 32u4 microcontroller?

Arduino code (simplified to highlight the problem):

```
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while(!Serial){}
}

void loop(){
  // wait for incoming serial data from Qt (code not shown)
  // record data
  // send data back.  In this example, send back some text: "abababab"
  for(unsigned int i=0;i<4;i++){
   Serial.write{0x61}; // "a"
   Serial.write{0x62}; // "b"
  }
}
```

Relevant Qt code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QtSerialPort> 
#include <QDataStream>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
  {
    ui->setupUi(this);
    microcontroller = new QSerialPort(this);

    // initialize the serial port (baud rate, parity etc.)

connect(microcontroller, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this, &MainWindow::readData);

void MainWindow::readData(){

 serialData += microcontroller->readAll();
 qDebug() << serialData;

}
```

Comment: which 32u4 based board are you using ? Leonardo ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't open the same COM port twice. If it is open by the Arduino IDE, it won't work on your Qt app.

Also, you should post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's hard to tell what could be wrong if you don't show us the code.